# Sql to Azure Blob to LogicApp

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am new Azure functions, One of my task is to read data from Sql database and upload that data as a csv file in azure Blob storage using Azure functions and then using logicapps to retreive it. I am stuck with Sql to file to Azure Blob

Comment: To be a proper SO question, it has to be more specific and to mention what you actually tried yourself and where you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the Azure Functions documentation. I did a quick internet search and found this article on how to access to SQL database from an Azure Function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup

Here is another article which shows how to upload content to blob storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output

Apply your learnings from both and you should be able to accomplish this task.

Comment: Will do, Thank you chris.

Answer (score 0):

What about if instead you create a trigger to start the logic apps when something happen in your DB. Interesting article here : https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/

you can then pass the information to a function to process the data and push the new csv file to the storage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows

Optionally you might need to transform what the trigger from sql returns you, there you can use the logic apps transform the input : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-transform